# Using immer.js - reassigning draft array reference results in same array reference in state

Tags: angular, ngrx, immer.js

I have this failing test using the produce method of immer.js:

```js
     it('should replace array reference in state', () => {
        let state = {
            someArray: [1],
        };
        const somArrayUpdate = [2, 3];

        state = produce(state, draft => {
            draft.someArray = somArrayUpdate;
        });
        console.log(state.someArray);
        // update external array
        somArrayUpdate.push(4);
        // expect that the state array is not the same reference with the external array
        console.log(state.someArray);
        expect(state.someArray).not.toBe(somArrayUpdate);
    });
```

You can see the failing test here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-gwrbgh

I am trying to understand why this is not working and also how should an array replacement be performed using immer.js (there are no relevant examples in the documentation AFAIK).

Comment: https://github.com/immerjs/immer/issues/339
Cross linking the answer provided by Github